# Expected value and variance of Autoregressive model

Tags: variance, expected-value, stationarity, autoregressive

I stumbled against this problem and found it hard and help would be much appreciated
We have the following equation

$Y_{t}-Y_{t-1}= 1/3(Y_{t-1}-Y_{t-2})+a+u_{t}$

Where $a$ is a parameter and $u_{t}$ is iid(0,$\sigma^{2}$)

Let $Y_{0}$=$Y_{1}$=$0$

I managed to prove that $Y_{t}$ is a non-stationary AR(2) process

But I can't figure out how to compute $E(\Delta Y_{t})$ and $V(\Delta Y_{t})$

And after that I am supposed to compute $E(Y_{t})$

Comment: You can do it recursively. Just take expectations of the both sides of the equation that you provided, use the linearity property of expectation and use the recursive strategy until you get $E[Y_1 - Y_0]$ on the right hand side.

Comment: sorry I don't quite get it

Comment: What exactly? Start with taking expectation of the both sides and using the fact that expecation is linear.